# Procedure to insert entry into table y when table x is updated

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Let's say there is a table in which only insert and update is allowed (table x) and another temporary table(table y) in which data is inserted whenever certain column's of the table x is updated.

So can someone please guide me how can this be done

Comment: You are looking for `TRIGGERS`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) to do that.

You probably could use something like the following:

```
DELIMITER ;;;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER UPDATE ON table_x FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF  OLD.certain_column != NEW.certain_column
        THEN

        INSERT INTO table_y
            ...
            ;

    END IF;

END;;;

DELIMITER ;
```

If you provide more details regarding the problem, I could update the answer to be more specific